# How to use lxc profile set?

Tags: lxc, lxd

I would like to edit LXD profiles from the command line. This is done by `lxc profile set`:

> `lxc profile get <profile> <key>`                Get profile
>   configuration.
>
> `lxc profile set <profile> <key> <value>`        Set profile
>   configuration.

What is the expected format of the `<key> <value>`? The output from `lxc show profile` suggests a dotted structure:

```
root@ubuntu ~# lxc profile show zoneminder
name: zoneminder
config:
  raw.lxc: lxc.aa_allow_incomplete=1
description: ""
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: zoneminder0
    type: nic
```

but I did not manage to `get` anything (not to mention - `set`). I tried various incantations (as an example `lxc profile get zoneminder name`, `lxc profile get zoneminder lxc.name`, ... to get the value of `name` above) but they all return nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic syntax to get values is:

```
$ lxc profile get default somekey
```

However, to get something, you need to set it first. It appears you can only set known key values, i.e. those that actively mean something to lxd:

```
$ lxc profile set default rubbish 1
error: Bad key: rubbish

$ lxc profile set default limits.cpu 1
```

... and then you can retrieve it:

```
$ lxc profile get default limits.cpu
1

$ lxc profile show default
name: default
config:
  limits.cpu: "1"
description: Default LXD profile
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: lxdbr0
    type: nic
```

Devices appear to be special; the regular get/set access the "config" sub-field of the profile, but you need to use special commands to manipulate devices:

```
$ lxc profile device get default eth0 nictype
bridged
```

Comment: Another example, to change default pool: `lxc profile device set default root pool newpool`

Answer (score 0):

Try `lxc profile edit <profile>` instead. It gives a better experience for editing profiles by opening inline editor.